# Accessing session cookies across domains with CNAME

Tags: session, authentication, cookies, dns

Let's say there is domain A and domain B and domain A sets a session cookie on the domain `.A.com`. Now set a CNAME record that points `subdomain.A.com` to `B.com`. Will the browser that has visited `subdomain.A.com` have access to the cookie that was originally set by `A.com`, even though it is a CNAME that points to `B.com`?

Answer (score 2):

No, CNAME is a DNS-level construct, and browsers do not take that into account at all. All it cares about is the host name in the URL.